# Flatten numpy array

Tags: python, numpy

Is there a simple way in NumPy to flatten type object array?

I know .flatten() method flattens non-object type arrays constructed from same size arrays:

```
I1 a = np.array([[1],[2],[3]])

I2 a.flatten()
O2 array([1, 2, 3])
```

however, I can't get dtype=object array flattened:

```
I4 b
O4 array([[1], [2, 3], [3]], dtype=object)

I5 b.flatten()
O5 array([[1], [2, 3], [3]], dtype=object)
```

Thanks.

Comment: The example is already as flat as it can be (`b.shape = (3,)`)! What exactly do you mean by flatten?

Comment: Yes, but practically, I want b to change into [1,2,3,3]

Answer (score 62, accepted):

if you want [1,2,3,3], try this then

```
np.hstack(b)
```

Comment: Nice. I was about to post this (which does the exact same thing): [x for bb in b for x in bb]

Comment: @urinieto actually the list comprehension-based method you posted is faster, although it's kinda nicer to have it settled in numpy's way.

Comment: how about for an array of 20k element?

Comment: @nye17 -- But at the end of the day, it's often nice to have a numpy array instead of a list.

Comment: @GökhanSever 20k wouldn't be a problem for modern computers, if you are really thresholded by speed in this kind of computation, I would say that you shouldn't have had an inhomogenous data array to begin with.

Comment: @mgilson true, although `np.array([x for bb in b for x in bb])` will do the job.

Comment: @nye17, For me, readability beats speed, since plot creation usually takes most of the time. np.hstack(b) is 12 characters total, whereas the latter is more than twice of this. For inhomogeneity argument, that's the nature of data I have. hstack helps me to bring them together so that I can perform bulk statistics between pair of different calculations.

Comment: @GökhanSever great, then `hstack` is the way to go!

Answer (score 0):

In case when your array does not contain more than one nested array, `np.hstack(arr)` function **won't work!**

Workaround:

```
arr = np.array([[0]])
if arr.any():
    arr = np.hstack(arr)
else:
    arr = arr.flatten()
```