# How to flatten an object array in numpy?

Tags: python, numpy

I have an array

```py
np.array([[[ 1,  2], [ 3, -4]],[[-1,  0]]], dtype=object)
```

and I want to flatten it to get something like:

```py
array([1,2,3,-4,-1,0], dtype=int32)
```

I tried [Flatten numpy array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11367243/flatten-numpy-array) but it raises a Value error

To be clear, my array is always an object array consists of multiple 2D and 1D arrays

Comment: You have an array of arrays, is that really what you want?

Comment: @NilsWerner yes

Comment: What's the shape?  If 1d, try `hstack`

Comment: @hpaulj It is an object array consisting of 1d and 2d arrays

Comment: In newer versions, the print shows which of the elements are arrays, eg. `np.array([np.array([1,2,3]), ...])`  Your print is ambiguous, but I'm guessing (2,) containing a (2,2) and (1,2).   If so then `vstack` should make a (3,2).

Comment: When you tried `hstack` what error did you get?  Full info please!

Answer (score 1):

```
In [333]: arr = np.array([[[ 1,  2], [ 3, -4]],[[-1,  0]]], dtype=object)                                       
In [334]: arr                                                                                                   
Out[334]: array([list([[1, 2], [3, -4]]), list([[-1, 0]])], dtype=object)
In [335]: arr.shape                                                                                             
Out[335]: (2,)
In [336]: np.vstack(arr)                                                                                        
Out[336]: 
array([[ 1,  2],
       [ 3, -4],
       [-1,  0]])
In [337]: np.vstack(arr).ravel()                                                                                
Out[337]: array([ 1,  2,  3, -4, -1,  0])
```

Answer (score 0):

If you dont know the depth of your nestet array you can do it like this:

```
l = np.array([[[ 1,  2],[ 3, -4]], [-1,  0]])

from collections.abc import Iterable

def flatten(l):
    returnlist=[]
    for elem in l:
        if isinstance(elem, Iterable):
            returnlist.extend(flatten(elem))
        else:
            returnlist.append(elem)

    return returnlist

np.array(flatten(l))
```

If its 2 dimensional you can go like that post suggest [How to make a flat list out of list of lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/952914/how-to-make-a-flat-list-out-of-list-of-lists):

```
flat_list = [item for sublist in l for item in sublist]
```

or just use numpys flatten.

By the way, your example is not two dimensional because of those double brackets, thats also why flatten() does not work:

`np.array([`**[[** `1,  2], [ 3, -4` **]]**`,[[-1,  0]]], dtype=object)`

Comment: Is there any simpler/faster method ?

Comment: Better data to start with would make it easier. You have a mix of a numpy array and lists here. But to answer the question: There might be, but at the moment i know for no faster method even though it probably exists.

Answer (score 0):

It's nested, but you can use `sum()` to do this:

```
nested_list_values = [[[ 1,  2], [ 3, -4]],[[-1,  0]]]
sum(sum(, []), [])
```

> [1, 2, 3, -4, -1, 0]

Or, with `itertools.chain()` if that feels more natural:

```
from itertools import chain

nested_list_values = [[[ 1,  2], [ 3, -4]],[[-1,  0]]]
list(chain(*chain(*nested_list_values)))
```

> [1, 2, 3, -4, -1, 0]